# yii2: ActionColumn on GridView not working with ActiveForm

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

Customised `ActionColumn` worked perfectly on my `GridView`, until I added an `ActiveForm` on the `GridView` so I can select multiple rows (with `CheckboxColumn`) and run the action on the whole items.

Nothing happen when I click on the action items, but it works when I copy/paste the path on the browser.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'showHeader' => true,
        'showOnEmpty'=>false,
        'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => '0'],
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'Referral',
            'Membership',
             /*other attributes*/
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionRef'],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>


    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Disable" id="DisableButton" >

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My "Disable" Button work perfectly in the form.

I tried to start the `ActiveForm` after `GridWiew`, but the button (naturally) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The default Yii2 gridview don't work for active view

I think you should use kartik [builder form](http://demos.krajee.com/builder) and [tabular form](http://demos.krajee.com/builder-details/tabular-form) extension.